# Multiply filter in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a problem with filtering data in my angularJS app. There is code:

```
<p>
<span>Lokalizacja: </span>
<select ng-model="location" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Wybierz lokalizacje...</option>
    <option value="Łepkowskiego D">Łepkowskiego D</option>
</select>
</p>

<p>
    <span>Liczba pokoi: {{rooms}}</span>
    <input type="range" ng-model="rooms" min="1" max="5">
</p>

<p>
    <span>Piętro: {{floor}}</span>
    <select ng-model="floor" class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Wybierz piętro</option>
        <option value="Parter">Parter</option>
        <option value="I">Piętro I</option>
        <option value="II">Piętro II</option>
        <option value="III">Piętro III</option>
        <option value="IV">Piętro IV</option>
        <option value="V">Piętro V</option>
        <option value="VI">Piętro VI</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Here is my ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="flat in flats | filter: location | filter: floor | filter: rooms">
    <td>{{flat.location}}</td>
    <td>{{flat.floor}}</td>
    <td>{{flat.surface}}</td>
    <td>{{flat.rooms}}</td>
    <td>{{flat.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

And here is example of data in controller:

```
{
    "location":"Łepkowskiego D",
    "floor":"I",
    "surface":55.70,
    "rooms":3,
    "price":6200
},
{
    "location":"Łepkowskiego D",
    "floor":"I",
    "surface":52.18,
    "rooms":3,
    "price":6300
},
```

My question is how to do a filter where in example i choose floor: I, rooms: 2 and in app will show all of records with first floor and 2 rooms, not like in this picture:

[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Z7h.png)

Best regards and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use filter like this in your ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="flat in flats | filter:{location:location, floor:floor, rooms:rooms}">
```

Answer (score 0):

That hapens because you are using chaining filters instead of comparing to an object mask that it should match. Therefore, you have to effor it's mask by setting filter like `filter:{ location: location, floor: floor, rooms: rooms }` to bring all objects with this set of properties. Also, at a first moment you have to init your `$scope.room` because when first loadaded it doesn's have a value until you change it's value.

The following snippet implements filter dependents and init your value.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.rooms = 3;
      $scope.flats = [{
         "location":"Łepkowskiego D",
         "floor":"I",
         "surface":55.70,
         "rooms":3,
         "price":6200
        },
        {
         "location":"Łepkowskiego A",
         "floor":"II",
         "surface":52.18,
         "rooms":4,
         "price":6300
        }];
    });
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,th{  
  padding:4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
      <p>
        <span>Lokalizacja: </span>
        <select ng-model="location" class="form-control">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Wybierz lokalizacje...</option>
         <option value="Łepkowskiego D">Łepkowskiego D</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        
        <p>
         <span>Liczba pokoi: {{rooms}}</span>
         <input type="range" ng-model="rooms" min="1" max="5">
        </p>
        
        <p>
         <span>Piętro: {{floor}}</span>
         <select ng-model="floor" class="form-control">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Wybierz piętro</option>
          <option value="Parter">Parter</option>
          <option value="I">Piętro I</option>
          <option value="II">Piętro II</option>
          <option value="III">Piętro III</option>
          <option value="IV">Piętro IV</option>
          <option value="V">Piętro V</option>
          <option value="VI">Piętro VI</option>
         </select>
        </p>
 
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
         <th>Location</th>
         <th>Floor</th>
         <th>Surface</th>
         <th>Liczba pokoi</th>
         <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="flat in flats | filter:{ location:location, floor:floor, rooms:rooms }">
         <td>{{flat.location}}</td>
         <td>{{flat.floor}}</td>
         <td>{{flat.surface}}</td>
         <td>{{flat.rooms}}</td>
         <td>{{flat.price}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```